# Display search result into DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf

I have been trying to figure out this error:

> A first chance exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in Toys Live.exe
>   Additional information: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

This is the string of code that is producing the error above:

```
DataRow[] returnRows = DS.Tables["Product"].Select("Typeoftoy='" + searchOut + "'");
```

The Object reference should be the following code below, unless I am missing something else.

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private SqlDataAdapter dAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
    private DataSet DS = new DataSet();
    private SqlConnection conConnect;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
```

This is the block of code I am currently working with to display the search results from a TextBox into a DataGrid in WPF.

```
private void SearchBTN_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        conConnect = new SqlConnection("Data Source=GERRY;Initial Catalog=toyDB;Integrated Security=True");

        dAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT Typeoftoy   FROM Product", conConnect);
        DS = new DataSet();

        if (tbSearch.Text.Length >= 1)
        {
            string searchOut = tbSearch.Text;
            int result = 0;

            dAdapter.Fill(DS, "MyDataBinding");

            DataRow[] returnRows = DS.Tables["Product"].Select("Typeoftoy='" + searchOut + "'");

            result = returnRows.Length;

            if (result > 0)
            {
                datagrid1.ItemsSource = returnRows.CopyToDataTable().DefaultView;
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("No Records Found");
            }

            conConnect.Close();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

A null reference exception means you are trying to use an object you have now instantiated with a "new" construct.  It is unclear what series of events that causes this.  Look at the line where you get the exception and you will find the class from which the method is throwing the exception is not instantiated.  Look through your code and make sure you instantiate it with "new" before you use it.

Comment: Error Code Line: DataRow[] returnRows = DS.Tables["Product"].Select("TypeofToy='" + searchOut + "'");  Here is the "new" you are talking about  DS = new DataSet(); This is declared only a line under my dAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter line code.

Comment: Since you are declaring new objects, then it is likely the call to `Tables["Product"]` is not returning anything.  You can try accessing it by index or it's probably that "Product" is not spelled as it should be intended.

Answer (score 0):

Im thinking that you have a problem with your SQL Query and you are not really populating you DataSet properly, then you try to access the Table property which may be null if the query didnt work as expected.

Set a breakpoint to the dAdapter.Fill method and make sure it outputs the expected result

Comment: When I use the dAdapter.Fill (DS, "MyDataBinding"); during a Button Click event to populate the DataGrid it works just fine. It retrieves the data from the DB Table and populates the grid with the data I have entered into the columns.

Comment: Then which line is throwing the NullReferenceException

Comment: Here is the Line of Code:: DataRow[] returnRows = DS.Tables["Product"].Select("TypeofToy='" + searchOut + "'");

Answer (score 0):

I have figured out the problem here is the problem then the solution::

The problem was in the DS.Tables["Product"]  access the table using its index in the DataSet rather than a name.

```
DataRow[] returnRows = DS.Tables["Product"].Select("Typeoftoy='" + searchOut + "'");
```

Solution, was removing the ["Product"] and setting its index to 0

```
 DataRow[] returnRows = DS.Tables[0].Select("Typeoftoy='" + searchOut + "'");
```